# XDebug profiler doesn't write files in apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xdebug

I'm using XDebug profiler on Ubuntu 18.04 with the simplest configuration possible:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
```

This is defined in `/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`, so it is used by both CLI and Apache. If I run a script in the CLI, I get the cachegrind dump in `/tmp` as expected. But if I run in Apache, I don't get any files. I've verified with `phpinfo()`, and the config is the same, i.e. it's supposed to save to `/tmp`. It even shows me the filename it wants to use in the header `X-Xdebug-Profile-Filename`, but nothing gets saved to the filesystem. AFAICT, everybody (including `www-data`) has write access to `tmp` (I mean, otherwise a lot of other things also woudn't work), so I wonder: Why can't I get dumps in Apache?

xdebug section of `phpinfo()` looks like this:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  Off Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump    2   2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  On  On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.remote_timeout   200 200
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   no value    no value
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

P.S.: I've also tried this on a different machine (same Ubuntu version). Since it worked fine for me in the past (around Ubuntu 16 I would say), I wonder if this is something that changed in a recent distro release?

P.P.S: I just tried again with a freshly installed Kubuntu 18.04 in a VM. No configuration was made except what is shown above, and it still doesn't work. so to me it looks like this is broken in Ubuntu in general for some reason?

P.P.P.S.: I've now made a new folder on the root dir `/xdebug` and did `chmod 777`. With this it works (even though `chmod 777` on the normal `/tmp`) folder had no effect. I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect that there is some sort of evil `systemd` magic at work (I've read about something called PrivateTMP somewhere that could be the cause of this)

Comment: make sure you use the same ini file in apache. usually cli ini file is different, so you may be running under a different config

Comment: it does use the same ini file, I can see it in `phpinfo()` on the server

Comment: ok then, check what user php runs as both from cli and apache, then check user permissions for /tmp

Comment: permissions for `/tmp` are `drwxrwxrwt`, the apache user is `www-data`. And I can upload files to the server normally, and sessioning also works, so I'm pretty sure Apache can write to tmp

Comment: This is a stupid question, but have you have restarted Apache after enabling the profiler (or making nay other changes to the php.ini file)? Can you post the xdebug info from phpinfo()?

Comment: yes, I restarted Apache. xdebug info looks like this (edit: doesn't fit into comment, I've added it to the question instead)

Comment: 1) If you do `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` and specify xdebug log for `xdebug.remote_log` -- will it generate any logs? 2) Anything like SELinux or alike active there?

Comment: 1) I've added both directives, but no log file is created. I tried `/tmp/xdebug.log` and also made a new folder `/test` with `chmod 777`, but nothing gets written. 2) Not as far as I know, unless that is standard in Ubuntu nowadays (how would I check?)

Comment: 1) Well -- check if you have SELinux or AppArmor installed, just google something like "ubuntu selinux status". I've mentioned SELinux because I remember the same "no debug, no logs" case when it was enabled for Apache (and since PHP runs by Apache, it may affect it as well). P.S. Consider using `@username` otherwise no notifications on new comments

Comment: 2) I know, it sounds stupid (especially since you have answered similar question) ... but double check that you are editing the right file .. and collect `phpinfo()` output in the same way where it does not work (via browser). P.S. Forgot to include `xdebug.remote_enable=1` for previous test, otherwise debug is completely disabled.

Comment: @LazyOne: ok, apparently I have AppArmor enabled (but not SELinux). I disabled it with  `systemctl stop apparmor && systemctl disable apparmor` and restarted Apache, but it made no difference

Comment: In such case I do not know what else it might be (not a Linux user myself).

Comment: @LazyOne 2) I added the `xdebug.remote_enable=1` line, and that works in the sense that Eclipse immediately picks it up and goes into the debugger. So I can step through the code, but I still don't get callgrind dumps

Comment: OK ... in such case lets try this: `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1` and use any xdebug browser extension that supports such profiling to trigger it (it will set special cookie that will be used on next request). Lets see if that will do any better.

Comment: @LazyOne I've added the setting and an extension, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. The button itself works, i.e. when I press it, I get the `X-Xdebug-Profile-Filename` header in the next request. But still nothing on disk

Comment: try setting a custom folder for xdebug log output

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thx, that did the trick! I'm pretty sure I tried it before already, but probably forgot one of the steps

Comment: if i add an answer will you mark it the correct one? :-)

Comment: @delboy1978uk Sure :-) Although I would still like to know why it's impossible to use the regular `/tmp` dir

Comment: it'll just be a user/group permissions thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem myself, and even though the permissions looked alright, for some reason it just wouldn't play nice.

If you set a custom log for xdebug profiler output (maybe in your home foolder or somewhere you know for sure can be written to), it shhould work.